# Substring extraction in R

Tags: r, string

I have a string which looks like this:

```
{"created_at":"Tue May 12 09:45:33 +0000 2015","id":598061439090196480,"id_str":"598061439090196480","text":"I've collected 72,455 gold coins! http:\/\/t.co\/eTEbfxpAr0 #iphone"}
```

And I want the resultant to be:

```
"Tue May 12 09:45:33 +0000 2015"  

598061439090196480

"598061439090196480"

"I've collected 72,455 gold coins! http:\/\/t.co\/eTEbfxpAr0 #iphone"
```

Separator works but it breaks a row for some strings and start a new row.
Please suggest some function where I can give the start and end pattern of a substring or a different approach would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have something in JSON format, use one of the JSON parsers.

Example:

```
string <- '{"created_at":"Tue May 12 09:45:33 +0000 2015","id":598061439090196480,"id_str":"598061439090196480","text":"I\'ve collected 72,455 gold coins! http://example.com/eTEbfxpAr0 #iphone"}'
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON(string)
# $created_at
# [1] "Tue May 12 09:45:33 +0000 2015"
# 
# $id
# [1] 5.980614e+17
# 
# $id_str
# [1] "598061439090196480"
# 
# $text
# [1] "I've collected 72,455 gold coins! http://example.com/eTEbfxpAr0 #iphone"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regmatches` function also. It's better to go with Ananda's because using parser specially created for parsing json files is the way to go.

```
> string <- '{"created_at":"Tue May 12 09:45:33 +0000 2015","id":598061439090196480,"id_str":"598061439090196480","text":"I\'ve collected 72,455 gold coins! http://t.co/eTEbfxpAr0 #iphone"}'
> regmatches(string, gregexpr("(?<=:)(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^,}]*)", string, perl=T))[[1]]
[1] "\"Tue May 12 09:45:33 +0000 2015\""                                  
[2] "598061439090196480"                                                  
[3] "\"598061439090196480\""                                              
[4] "\"I've collected 72,455 gold coins! http://t.co/eTEbfxpAr0 #iphone\""
```